# How do I get Custom Field Post Object data in WordPress REST API

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm wondering how I can get the Post Object data from a custom field with WordPress Rest API.

Here's my JS:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const getEvents = () => {
  return axios
    .get('https://127.0.0.1/wp-json/wp/v2/events')
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      return res
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
    })
    .then({})
}

getEvents()
```

It returns the object, but the Advanced Custom Fields for class_type as an example returns a string of the ID, which is the Class post type Id for that Event.

[image]

How can I get further?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is to create a custom route...

File: routes/events-route.php

```
<?php

class Events_Rest_Router {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->register_routes();
    }

    protected function register_routes() {
        add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
            $namespace = 'api/v1/';

            register_rest_route($namespace, '/events', array(
                'methods' => 'GET',
                'callback' => array( $this, 'get_events' ),
            ));
        });
    }

    public function get_events($request) {
        $output = array();

        $args = array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'event',
            'meta_key' => 'start_date',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($query -> have_posts()) {
            while ($query -> have_posts()) {
                $query->the_post();

                $post = get_post(get_the_ID());

                if ($request['type'] == $post->location) {
                    array_push($output, array(
                        'id' => $post->ID,
                        'class_type' => get_field('class_type')
                    ));
                }
            }
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();

        return $output;

    }
}

new Events_Rest_Router;
```

Add the route to your functions.php

File: functions.php

```
require_once 'routes/events-route.php';
```